# How to execute all queries in graphql inside gatsby-node.js?

Tags: javascript, graphql, content-management-system, gatsby

I want to execute multiple queries nodes at the same time in `gatsby-node.js` in order to create pages accordingly to my query , so  these are the queries :

```
{
      allPrismicLastPosts {
        nodes {
          data {
            blogs {
              blog {
                document {
                  ... on PrismicBlog {
                    uid
                  }
                  ... on PrismicCulture {
                    uid
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      allPrismicMainBlogs {
        nodes {
          data {
            blogs {
              blog {
                document {
                  ... on PrismicBlogMain {
                    uid
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
}
```

So in order to `createPage` in `gatsby-node.js` I need both the  `uid` of `allPrismicLastPosts`  and `allPrismicMainBlogs`  from these queries , this is what I 've tried :

```
{
      allPrismicLastPosts {
        nodes {
          data {
            blogs {
              blog {
                document {
                  ... on PrismicBlog {
                    uid
                  }
                  ... on PrismicCulture {
                    uid
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      allPrismicMainBlogs {
        nodes {
          data {
            blogs {
              blog {
                document {
                  ... on PrismicBlogMain {
                    uid
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
}
```

But this will only fetch the `allPrismicLastPosts`  `uid` instead I want all the `uid` ,Any idea to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You have many ways of doing this. The easiest one is to assign each result of the query to a variable like:

```
const posts = await graphql(`
  query {
    allPrismicLastPosts {
      nodes {
        data {
          blogs {
            blog {
              document {
                ... on PrismicBlog {
                  uid
                }
                ... on PrismicCulture {
                  uid
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`);
const mainBlog = await graphql(`
  query {
    allPrismicMainBlogs {
      nodes {
        data {
          blogs {
            blog {
              document {
                ... on PrismicBlogMain {
                  uid
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`);
```

Then you just need to loop through each variable:

```
  posts.data.allPrismicLastPosts.nodes.forEach(node => {
    createPage({
       // your data here
      }),
  });

  mainBlog.data.allPrismicMainBlogs.nodes.forEach(node => {
    createPage({
       // your data here
      }),
  });
```